# How to loft with ellipses to create a 3d hollow pipe in MATLAB or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, 3d

I have a series of ellipses and know their dimensions and locations of their centers. I would like to plot them and loft through each of them to create a 3d pipe.

Is there a lofting feature in MATLAB or in a 3D library in Python (If so, which library)? In addition, I would like to add these ellipses in real time so staying in MATLAB would be preferable. But, if there is a Python solution, how would I implement it to communicate between the MATLAB and Python file to maintain the real time link.

I would imagine it would look something like this except hollow:

[image: .]

It would be great if you could provide a solution for this either in MATLAB or Python.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in Python implementations of the answers above:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from matplotlib import cm

#Create the profile
Radii = [1, 1.5, 1, 0.8, 1.3, 0.6, 0.5]
Zradii = [0, 1, 5, 10, 12, 14, 16]

radius = CubicSpline(Zradii, Radii, bc_type=((1, 0.5), (1, 0.0)))

# Make data
thetarange = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
zrange = np.linspace(min(Zradii), max(Zradii),100)
X = [radius(z)*np.cos(thetarange) for z in zrange]
Y = [radius(z)*np.sin(thetarange) for z in zrange]
Z = np.array([[z] for z in zrange])

# Plot the surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim3d(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 20)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

#Plot the circles
for zz in Zradii:
    XX = radius(zz)*np.cos(thetarange)
    YY = radius(zz)*np.sin(thetarange)
    ax.plot(XX,YY,zz, lw=1, color='k')

plt.show();
```

[Lofted circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIA3x.png)

And for the ellipses:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from matplotlib import cm

#Create the profile
Zradii = [0, 1, 5, 10, 12, 14, 16]
ARadii = [1, 1.5, 1, 0.8, 1.3, 0.6, 0.5] #Major axis
BRadii = [0.5, 1, 1.2, 1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5] # Minor Axis
XOFFSET = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]    # X Offset of each ellipse
YOFFSET = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]    # Y Offset of each ellipse

aradius = CubicSpline(Zradii, ARadii, bc_type=((1, 0.5), (1, 0.0)))
bradius = CubicSpline(Zradii, BRadii, bc_type=((1, 0.5), (1, 0.0)))
xoffset = CubicSpline(Zradii, XOFFSET)
yoffset = CubicSpline(Zradii, YOFFSET)

# Make data
npoints=100
thetarange = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, npoints)
zrange = np.linspace(min(Zradii), max(Zradii), npoints)

X = [xoffset(z) + aradius(z)*np.cos(thetarange) for z in zrange]
Y = [yoffset(z) + bradius(z)*np.sin(thetarange) for z in zrange]
Z = np.array([[z] for z in zrange])

# Plot the surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(-2, 5)
ax.set_ylim3d(-2, 5)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 20)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

#Plot the ellipses
for zz in Zradii:
    XX = xoffset(zz) + aradius(zz)*np.cos(thetarange)
    YY = yoffset(zz) + bradius(zz)*np.sin(thetarange)
    ax.plot(XX,YY,zz, lw=1, color='k')

plt.show();
```

[Lofted ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo55T.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a two step process.

First, create the profile you want by fitting a curve to the desired radii like:

```matlab
% Create the profile
Zradii = [0 1 5 10 12 14 16];
Rradii = [1 1.5 1 0.8 1.3 0.6 0.5];
pp = spline(Zradii,[0.5 Rradii 0]);
```

here I defined the rings at heights given in `Zradii` with corresponding radius given in `Rradii`.

Next, create the loft surface by plotting that profile using [`fsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html) like this:

```matlab
% Loft
r = @(u,v) ppval(pp,v);
funx = @(u,v) r(u,v).*cos(u);
funy = @(u,v) r(u,v).*sin(u);
funz = @(u,v) v;
fsurf(funx,funy,funz,[0 2*pi min(Zradii) max(Zradii)]) 
camlight
axis square;
view(70,10);
```

The result of this example looks like:
[image: picture of plot]

**Extension**

The previous method can be extended to other arbitrary shapes. As an example, we change from circles to ellipses using the equation:

[image: equation of ellipse]

The previous code could then be modified to look like this:

```matlab
%% Create the profile
Z = [0 1 5 10 12 14 16];
A = [1 1.5 1 0.8 1.3 0.6 0.5]; % Major Axis
B = [0.5 1 1.2 1 0.5 0.7 0.5]; % Minor Axis
X = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2];    % X Offset of each ellipse
Y = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2];    % Y Offset of each ellipse
ppA = spline(Z,[0.5 A 0]);
ppB = spline(Z,[0.5 B 0]);
ppX = spline(Z,X);
ppY = spline(Z,Y);

%% Loft
ellipse = @(t,a,b) a.*b./sqrt((a.*cos(t)).^2 + (b.*sin(t)).^2);
r = @(u,v) ellipse(u, ppval(ppA,v), ppval(ppB,v));
funx = @(u,v) r(u,v).*cos(u) + ppval(ppX,v);
funy = @(u,v) r(u,v).*sin(u) + ppval(ppY,v);
funz = @(u,v) v;
fsurf(funx,funy,funz,[0 2*pi min(Z) max(Z)],'linestyle','none') 
camlight
axis square;
view(80,5);

%% Add the ellipses in black
hold on
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
arrayfun(@(z)plot3(funx(t,z),funy(t,z),z*ones(size(t)),'k','Linewidth',2),Z)
hold off
```

which produces the following plot where the ellipses that generated the loft are shown in black:

[image: loft with ellipses]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I was wondering how I could make the circles become ellipses as my data consists of a major and minor radius.  I tried to add another variable for the second radius but it would not let me add more than two variables for the equation. In addition, I would like to offset the centers of these circles/ellipses from the current coordinates of (0,0). Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to add variable x and y offset for each ellipse? Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @vinayksk I added the offsets for each ellipse to the code, it makes for quite a strange looking jug but I hope it illustrates how this could be used with just about any shape you could parameterize.

Comment: Thank you, this should be fine. I have implemented this code to analyze a video. Every five frames, my program determines the X and Y coordinates and X and Y offsets of a circle in the video and adds these values to their respective array (I preset the Z-Values). This generates a 3d model of a tube as I hoped. I would like to make this program work with a live video feed. I have figured out how to get the frames from a live video but would like to know how I can see visually see each layer being added to my 3D model in the popup without generating a new model after each frame.